# Featured image from custom to Wordpress database

Tags: database, mysql, import, bulk-import

I want to adapt my old custom website database (composed of only one table) to Wordpress database.

All data has been correctly imported in both tables (`wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta`) with a php code that I can share if needed.

Here is a screenshot of my `wp_posts` table...[image: wp_posts screenshot]

...and a screenshot of my `wp_postmeta` table (I imported only one entry to facilitate understanding).
[image: wp_postmeta screenshot]

As you can see, `wp_posts/post_parent` column of `id` 2 (referring to the featured image) is well linked to `id` 1 (which is the post).

But in my wordpress admin panel, I still have no linked featured image.[image: blank featured image]

**Is there another place where the image and the post have to be linked?**

Comment: Make sure that image exists at address mentioned in `guid` column. Give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, it exists. When I access to the URL in `guid`, I can see the image. And it is correctly imported in the Media library.

Comment: OK, there should be a record in the `wp_postmeta` table which registers the thumbnail ID against the `post_id` with `meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'` . Does this record exists for your post?

Comment: you can check if a thumbnail exist by `$featured image_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', true );`

Comment: When I set a featured image regularly (with the button in the admin panel), I didn't have any '_thumbnail_id' entry. The thumbnail doest exist as I can see it in the Media Library.

Comment: Even if it exists, it will not be shown unless it is linked to post through `_thumbnail_id` in `wp_postmeta` table.

Comment: I added it with the following data:   `meta_key = _thumbnail_id` || `meta_value = 1` (post id). Nothing changed.

Comment: No, it should be `post_id = 1`  `meta_key = _thumbnail_id` and   `meta_value = 2` as per screenshots shared in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90095/discussion-between-supershivas-and-qaisar-feroz).